# EEVEE doesn't render textures

Tags: rendering, texturing, eevee-render-engine

I can't find out, why EEVEE won't render my textures (third image). I created the UV map and assigned the material to the Object. Render Preview (first image) shows the texture, but final rendering with F12 doesn't. When rendering with cycles (second image) it is rendering the texture, but it still looks wrong.

[image: Render Preview]
[image: Cycles Render]
[image: EEVEE Render]

Comment: Are you sure you don't have duplicated geometry?

Comment: You are right, i thought EEVEE wouldn't render it when hiding it in the collection...
Thank you very much!